# How to do I do this specific expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to get a certain expression in QGIS right, but because I am quite new to QGIS expressions, I cannot quite get it right.

Basically I want another field, to have specific kind of text based on the value of the pre-existing field. In this case, when the height of a tree ("Height" field) has the following values, the following text will be displayed:

> - <6 meters: >6 meters 3rd category
> - between 6-12 meters: 2nd category
> - >12 meters: 1st category

How exactly do I do this and what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

As for a side note, should I better do this using **[AutoFields](https://github.com/gacarrillor/autofields)** plugin, so I am sure it happens automatically?

Comment: Regarding your last question, definitely! Use AutoFields to get the 'category' field up-to-date (e.g., when you insert or modify heights). Just use the expression given by @armoraer in the AutoFields dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN "Hoogte" <= 6 THEN '6 meter, 3rde categorie'
  WHEN "Hoogte" >= 6 AND "Hoogte" <= 12 THEN '6-12 meter, 2de categorie'
  ELSE '12 meter, 1ste categorie'
END
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "autofields" though?

Comment: Beat me to it, good answer. To note, the "Hoogte" field must be numeric for this to work. The autofields, might refer to virtual fields, which can generate a field automatically based on this query. But probably best left for another question.

Comment: [AutoFields](https://github.com/gacarrillor/autofields) is a QGIS plugin that updates field values based on expressions. It writes the updated values directly in the source data.